# pip gmane can't import

Tags: python, django

I have already install the gmane, for sure i have run the upgrade.

```
pip install gmane --upgrade
```

And then it show me those:

> 'Requirement already up-to-date: gmane in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages'

```
>>> import gmane
```

It's shows me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/code/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gmane/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .networkEvolution import NetworkEvolution
  File "/root/code/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gmane/networkEvolution.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .pca import *
  File "/root/code/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gmane/pca.py", line 79
    def __init__(self,*metrics,final_dimensions=2,draw=False):
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone help?

Comment: It doesn't look like `gmane` actually supports Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have review the error, found the error 'syntax error'.So i have write a very simple sample to confirm it.

```
class MyGmane:
    def __init__(self,*meteris ,final_dimensions=2,draw=False):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mg = MyGmane()
```

I got the following error:

```
python $python q.py 
  File "q.py", line 2
    def __init__(self,*meteris ,final_dimensions=2,draw=False):
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After i change the order inside the init method like below:

```
def __init__(self,final_dimensions=2,draw=False,*meteris):
```

And then it work,so I have modify this file (line 79)

> "/root/code/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gmane/pca.py"
>   It's also work, so i guess there are maybe have a bug on 'game'!